# Most elegant way to copy type alias class to original collection

Tags: c#

Looking for a most elegant way to copy dictionary type alias to original collection.

````
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
public class SmallDictionary: Dictionary<string, JToken>
public class NestedDictionary : Dictionary<string, SmallDictionaly>

using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using Microsoft.Azure.Adp.Configuration.Events.Entities;
using Newtonsoft.Json.Linq;

public static Dictionary<string, Dictionary<string, JToken>> ToDictionary(this NestedDictionary configurationEntry)
{
   Dictionary<string, Dictionary<string, JToken>> resultDictionary = new Dictionary<string, Dictionary<string, JToken>>();
   foreach (KeyValuePair<string, SmallDictionary> pair in configurationEntry)
   {
      resultDictionary.Add(pair.Key, pair.Value);
   }
   return resultDictionary;
}
```
````

Comment: basically found shorter way to do this, which also create a new collection


`return configurationEntry.ToDictionary(entry => entry.Key, entry =>  (Dictionary<string, JToken>)entry.Value);`

Comment: This question currently has 3 votes to close it as off-topic due to lack of context. We really can't review questions that don't provide the requirements or show the usage of the code being reviewed. I suggest you read or re-read the [help center](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/help/how-to-ask) for how to ask good questions on code review.

Comment: @pacmaninbw and to make matters worse, I believe I misunderstood the question.

Comment: The current question title of your question is too generic to be helpful. Please edit to the site standard, which is for the title to simply **state the task accomplished by the code**. Please see [**How do I ask a good question?**](https://CodeReview.StackExchange.com/help/how-to-ask).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You definitely don't want to extend a type in order to alias it.

This introduces complexity, is not idiomatic, and most importantly doesn't create an alias.

I believe what you're looking for is the type alias syntax

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;

using SmallDictionary = Dictionary<string, JToken>;
using NestedDictionary = Dictionary<string, SmallDictionaly>;
```

As their name implies, type aliases do not create any new types, they simply introducing a scoped alias that refers to the aliased type.

The only real drawback to type aliases is that they cannot be generic.

Moving on the the logic itself,

There's no need to write a loop over the dictionary entries to copy them into it new dictionary.

`Dictionary<TKey, TValue>` provides a constructor which takes an `IEnumerable<KeyValuePair<TKey, TValue>` allowing us to specify its initial contents.

```
return new Dictionary<string, Dictionary<string, JToken>>(configurationEntry);
```

or

```
return new NestedDictionary(configurationEntry);
```

Thanks to the type alias

Comment: Thanks for an answer, accepting your answer, also can't gave up on type alias, since it's design guideline of my task :(

Comment: You mean you have a requirement to create subtypes that don't add any functionality butter nominally differentiated from their base types? That's a very odd guideline. What's the use case?

Comment: You asked the correct questions, what is the use case and what are the requirements. Just next time don't answer a question until the use cases and requirements are clear.

Comment: Use case is just to give name to complex dictionaries in domain objects of ASP.Net web service, since it used in a multiple places, we didn't wanted to use type alias, but actual class.

Comment: That rational seems weak. It's also an abuse of incidental extensibility. Consider sealed types and value types. For example your approach wouldn't work for `KeyValuePair<string, IEnumerable<Func<string, bool>>>`.